# How to calculate the confidence interval of the x-intercept in a linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, bootstrap, inverse-prediction

Since standard error of a linear regression is usually given for the response variable, I'm wondering how to obtain confidence intervals in the other direction - e.g. for an x-intercept. I'm able to visualize what it might be, but I'm sure there must be a straightforward way to do this. Below is an example in R of how to visualize this:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:10
a <- 20
b <- -2
y <- a + b*x + rnorm(length(x), mean=0, sd=1)

fit <- lm(y ~ x)
XINT <- -coef(fit)[1]/coef(fit)[2]

plot(y ~ x, xlim=c(0, XINT*1.1), ylim=c(-2,max(y)))
abline(h=0, lty=2, col=8); abline(fit, col=2)
points(XINT, 0, col=4, pch=4)
newdat <- data.frame(x=seq(-2,12,len=1000))

# CI
pred <- predict(fit, newdata=newdat, se.fit = TRUE) 
newdat$yplus <-pred$fit + 1.96*pred$se.fit 
newdat$yminus <-pred$fit - 1.96*pred$se.fit 
lines(yplus ~ x, newdat, col=2, lty=2)
lines(yminus ~ x, newdat, col=2, lty=2)

# approximate CI of XINT
lwr <- newdat$x[which.min((newdat$yminus-0)^2)]
upr <- newdat$x[which.min((newdat$yplus-0)^2)]
abline(v=c(lwr, upr), lty=3, col=4)
```

[image]

Comment: You could bootstrap this: `library(boot); 
sims <- boot(data.frame(x, y), function(d, i) {
  fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = d[i,])
  -coef(fit)[1]/coef(fit)[2]
}, R = 1e4); 
points(quantile(sims$t, c(0.025, 0.975)), c(0, 0))`. For inverse prediction intervals the help file of `chemCal:::inverse.predict` gives the following reference which might also help deriving a CI: Massart, L.M, Vandenginste, B.G.M., Buydens, L.M.C., De Jong, S., Lewi, P.J., Smeyers-Verbeke, J. (1997) Handbook of Chemometrics and Qualimetrics: Part A, p. 200

Comment: @Roland -  Thanks for this. Very helpful. Any idea why the bootstrap routine produces noticeably narrower intervals than method I show?

Comment: What you show in the graph is not the CI for the intercept. You show the points where the lower and upper confidence lines of the predictions cross the axis.

Comment: Not sure that I understand the issue there - these would seem to be the predicted x-intercepts at the extremes of the coefficient SEs.

Comment: The points where your blue lines cross the axis are the lower/upper (resp.) confidence limits corresponding to the points where your blue lines cross the prediction line. These are not directly related to the confidence interval of the x intercept.

Comment: Often in linear regression one has a model that says something like this: $$ Y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + \varepsilon_i \quad \text{where } \varepsilon_1,\ldots\varepsilon_n \sim \text{i.i.d. } N(0,\sigma^2), $$so that the $Y$s are treated as random and the $x$s as fixed.  That may be justified by saying you're looking for a conditional distribution given the $x$s. In practice if you take a new sample, it is usually not only the $Y$s but also the $x$s that change, suggesting in some circumstances they should also be considered random. I wonder if this bears upon the propriety of$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$finding a confidence interval for the $x$-intercept? $\qquad$

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q="inverse+regression"

Comment: Any chances you could validate my answer? Thanks.

Comment: @AdrienRenaud - It would seem to me that your answer is overly simplistic given the asymmetric aspects that I mentioned, and are highlighted by the bootstrapping exercise that Roland illustrated. If I'm not asking too much, maybe you could expand on the likelihood approach that you mentioned.

Comment: You didn't mention the asymmetric aspect in your question and it was not obvious from the figure. So it doesn't really seem fair ;) If your fit procedure return symmetrical confidence interval (ci) on the parameters, then the ci on the intercept will be symmetric.

Comment: @AdrienRenaud - If I didn't elaborate the question fully, I'm sorry about that - I just want to make sure that we have a good canonical answer here. Both my (simplistic) approach and the bootstrapping approach indicate an asymmetric interval, and this seems likely given the assumptions of a linear regression. I will up the ante with a bounty if that motivates :-)

Comment: I checked your procedure using Neyman construction and a theoretical approach. We still have undercoverage, but increasing the number of data points could maybe solve that issue. Do you want to try with my script? My theoretical approach combined with OLS properties could indicate that your result is optimal. If we have coverage and optimality, we might have a great answer to this question.

Comment: I checked that we have perfect coverage (within 1% statistical uncertainty) when using 100 data points. So we have validity and optimality! The two desired properties of a ci! I have very little time those days to update my answer but I very much like bounty :)

Comment: @AdrienRenaud - I think you definitely deserve the bounty for your efforts. I finally came across an R package that does inverse regression (investr), but it gives different results. If you're interested, [here's a vignette](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2014-1/greenwell-kabban.pdf)

Comment: I have included investr in my little study. It gives same result as MIB and CAPITANI-POLLASTRI with 100 data points (be sure to set `mean.response=TRUE` when calling `calibrate`). For 10 data points, the ci is different and investr coverage is perfect. So investr should be the preferred solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## How to calculate the confidence interval of the x-intercept in a linear regression?

### Asumptions

- Use the simple regression model $y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + \varepsilon_i$.
- Errors have normal distribution conditional on the regressors $\epsilon | X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 I_n)$
- Fit using ordinary least square

### 3 procedures to calculate confidence interval on x-intercept

- Taylor expansion (easy to use)
- Marc in the box method (MIB)
- CAPITANI-POLLASTRI (https://boa.unimib.it/retrieve/handle/10281/43053/64388/DECAPITANI_Pollastri.pdf)

#### First order Taylor expansion

Your model is $Y=aX+b$ with estimated standard deviation $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_b$ on $a$ and $b$ parameters and estimated covariance $\sigma_{ab}$.
You solve

$$aX+b=0 \Leftrightarrow X= \frac{-b} a.$$

Then the standard deviation $\sigma_X$ on $X$ is given by:

$$\left( \frac {\sigma_X} X \right)^2 = \left( \frac {\sigma_b} b \right)^2 + \left( \frac {\sigma_a} a \right)^2 - 2 \frac{\sigma_{ab}}{ab}.$$

#### MIB

See code from Marc in the box at [How to calculate the confidence interval of the x-intercept in a linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221630/how-to-calculate-the-confidence-interval-of-the-x-intercept-in-a-linear-regressi/).

#### CAPITANI-POLLASTRI

CAPITANI-POLLASTRI provides the Cumulative Distribution Function and Density Function for the ratio of two correlated Normal random variables. It can be used to compute confidence interval of the x-intercept in a linear regression. This procedure gives (almost) identical results as the ones from MIB.

Indeed, using ordinary least square and assuming normality of the errors, $\hat\beta \sim \mathcal{N}(\beta, \sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1})$ (verified) and $\hat{\beta}$'s are correlated (verified).

The procedure is the following:

- get OLS estimator for $a$ and $b$.
- get the variance-covariance matrix and extract, $\sigma_a, \sigma_b, \sigma_{ab}=\rho\sigma_a\sigma_b$.
- Assume that $a$ and $b$ follow a Bivariate Correlated Normal distribution, $\mathcal{N}(a, b, \sigma_a, \sigma_b, \rho)$. Then the density function and Cumulative Distribution Function of $x_{intercept}= \frac{-b}{a}$ are given by CAPITANI-POLLASTRI.
- Use the Cumulative Distribution Function of $x_{intercept}= \frac{-b}{a}$ to compute desired quantiles and set a cofidence interval.

### Comparaison of the 3 procedures

The procedures are compared using the following data configuration:

- x <- 1:10
- a <- 20
- b <- -2
- y <- a + b*x + rnorm(length(x), mean=0, sd=1)

10000 diferent sample are generated and analyzed using the 3 methods. The code (R) used to generate and analyze can be found at: https://github.com/adrienrenaud/stackExchange/blob/master/crossValidated/q221630/answer.ipynb

- MIB and CAPITANI-POLLASTRI give equivalent results.
- First order Taylor expansion differs significantly from the the two other methods.
- MIB and CAPITANI-POLLASTRI suffers from under-coverage. The 68% (95%) ci is found to contain the true value 63% (92%) of the time.
- First order Taylor expansion suffers from over-coverage. The 68% (95%) ci is found to contain the true value 87% (99%) of the time.

### Conclusions

The x-intercept distribution is asymmetric. It justify a asymmetric confidence interval. MIB and CAPITANI-POLLASTRI give equivalent results. CAPITANI-POLLASTRI have a nice theorical justification and it gives grounds for MIB. MIB and CAPITANI-POLLASTRI suffers from moderate under-coverage and can be used to set confidence intervals.

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer. Does this method imply that the standard error of the x-intercept is symmetric? The prediction intervals in my figure imply that this is not the case, and I have seen reference to this elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, it does imply a symmetric interval. If you want an asymmetric one, you could use a profile likelihood treating your model parameters as nuisance parameters. But it's more work :)

Comment: Could you explain more in detail how you get that expression for $(\sigma_X/X)^2$ ?

Comment: @fcop  It's a Taylor expansion. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend bootstrapping the residuals:

```
library(boot)

set.seed(42)
sims <- boot(residuals(fit), function(r, i, d = data.frame(x, y), yhat = fitted(fit)) {

  d$y <- yhat + r[i]

  fitb <- lm(y ~ x, data = d)

  -coef(fitb)[1]/coef(fitb)[2]
}, R = 1e4)
lines(quantile(sims$t, c(0.025, 0.975)), c(0, 0), col = "blue")
```

[image: resulting plot]

What you show in the graph are the points where the lower/upper limit of the confidence band of the predictions cross the axis. I don't think these are the confidence limits of the intercept, but maybe they are a rough approximation.

Comment: Great - this already looks more reasonable than the example from your comment. Thanks again.